# Why is the natural filtration of Brownian motion not $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ for all $t$?

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, filtrations

I'm trying to get a sense of what the $\sigma$-algebras in a filtration actually contain. More specifically, suppose $W_t$ is standard $\mathbb{R}$-Brownian motion defined on a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, (\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}, \mathbb{P})$ where $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is the natural filtration given by $W_t$. Now $W_t$ is a Normal random variable, which has support on $(-\infty, \infty)$, so in my mind it seems reasonable then that $\mathcal{F}_t=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ (since I can measure the probability of $W_t$ essentially being in any "nice" subset of $\mathbb{R}$).

However, since a filtration describes a "flow of information", it clearly is not the case that $\mathcal{F}_t=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ for all $t \geq 0$, since then is nothing gained from "being at $t$ rather than $s < t$".

On the other hand, if I were to simulate a sample path of $W_t$, clearly if $W_2=5$, I can sample $W_6$ from $N(5, 1)$, so clearly I have the "information" that I should "start at $5$".

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: $\mathcal F_t$ has nothing to do with the support. If $X \sim N(0,1)$ then $\sigma (X)$ may or may not be $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ depending on exactly where and how the variable $X$ is defined.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I suppose the way I'm looking at it is that $\mathcal{F}$ contains all the events for which we can assign probabilities for the random variable $W_t$. In my mind, $W_t$ can take any value along the real line so I thought therefore $\mathcal{F}_t$ must contain all "nice" subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. But maybe this is not the correct way to look at it? I guess I don't understand why the $\sigma$-algebra changes and not the probability measure itself (also maybe not the correct way to look at it).

Comment: You can define a random variable $X$ on $(0,1)$ with Borel sets and Lebesgue measure such that $X$ has standard normal distribution. In this case $\sigma (X)$ is the Borel sigma algebra of $(0,1)$. In general $\sigma (X)$ is a sigma algebra on $\Omega$, the sample space, and it is not a sigma algebra on the real line at all.

Comment: Ah, I had tacitly assumed $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$ for $\mathbb{R}$-Brownian motion. I need to understand a bit better what the $\sigma$-field generated from a random variable actually means, so thank you for pointing me in that direction.